# Visual studio C++ Assembly | Meaning of the brackets?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, addressing-mode, intel-syntax

I am trying to compare the assembly for two pieces of code and they look like shown below. My question is if the additions in `[esp+4] [esp+8] [esp+0Ch]` are performed at run-time, or somehow resolved before that.

Version 1

```
00FE104D  mov         eax,dword ptr [esp+4]  
00FE1051  imul        eax,dword ptr [esp+8]  
00FE1056  mov         esi,dword ptr [esp+0Ch]
```

Version 2

```
00FE104D  mov         eax,dword ptr [x]  
00FE1051  imul        eax,dword ptr [y]  
00FE1056  mov         esi,dword ptr [z]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's of course performed at runtime. "resolving" it before would be pointless.

```
mov eax,dword ptr [x]
```

means: take whatever `DWORD` pointed by `x` and put it into `eax`. In C it would be something like this:

```
   DWORD x;
   ...
   eax = *((DWORD*)x);
```

---

```
   mov eax,dword ptr [x + 4]
```

would be something like this in C

```
   DWORD x;
   ...
   eax = *((DWORD*)(x + 4));
```

Comment: Ok thank you for clarifying, as a second question, is there a difference in performance between version 1 and version 2? (with or without those additions).

Comment: `*((DWORD*)x)` <-- Wouldn't it be `*((DWORD*)&x)`? The address is the address of `x`, not the value stored at `x` treated as an address.

Comment: @Michael this is more pseudo code just to explain what the assembly instruction does. So, yes, in this sample `x` contains a 32 bit address.

Comment: Well, if it's not clear exactly how we should interpret the explanation, then the answer gets a bit confusing. If it's C then it seems like there should be an ampersand before `x`, because that's what the assembly code really means. If it's not C then there should probably be some kind of explanation of what those expressions mean in this language.